# URL Rewrite by custom router URL

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, redirect-url, router

I am using Magento version 2.2.6

I have already tried with `Marketing >> URL Rewrite >> Add New URL Rewrite` add custom URL, but it's not working when we use it with question mark in URL. It's working with / (slash), though.

I have URL like this `mydomain.com/product.asp?product=977`, and I want it to be rewritten to this `mydomain.com` (redirect to the root of the domain)

Also, I have another example `mydomain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=lim` and I want to redirect to this `mydomain.com/ingpage/about-lim.html`

Can anyone suggest to me how to do this via custom programming in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

Please try  this I have found that solutions.Below define in root .htaccess file inside code use it

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=tank123$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /mage229/men.html [QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^color=50$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /mage229/men/tops-men.html [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the htaccess configuration file on web servers running the Apache Web Server software and run a command with the below syntax:

Open .htaccess in Magento 2 Root FOlder

**Redirect 301 [old URL] [New URL]**

Eg:

```
Redirect 301 oldpath.html newpath.html
```

Notes* Make sure don't use full URL and put in last

Comment: I have this type of urls (many different different urls) product.asp?product=977  how to do this ?